# How to shorten date in telescope app?

Tags: date, meteor, telescope

[image: Current date]

I am using the telescope app. Currently in my post title template I am using scheduledAt to show a date when an event will be. I would like to shorten the date to just **Thu May 07 2015** but I don't really know how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Telescope, there's a helper named `formatDate` specifically designed for that purpose, just call it in your template like this :

```
{{formatDate scheduledAt "ddd MMMM DD YYYY"}}
```

Under the hood, it's using `momentjs` to display the date object.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Or, for full month: "ddd MMMM DD YYYY"